# Solution of vectorized equation

Tags: vector-spaces, matrix-equations

I am looking for a solution (or approximate solution) for the following
equations with vectorization. Let $X$ be $m\times n$ matrix of unknown
parameters, $A,B$ and $C$ are comfortable matrices (i.e., $A$ be $m\times m$, $B$ be $n\times n$, $C$ be $m\times n$), $vec$ is the
vectorization, what's the typical solution of
\begin{equation}
\
vec\left( AX+XB\right) =vec\left( C\right)
\
\end{equation}
looks like? Is there anyway to get a solution of $X$ in a simple formula? I am looking for a solution of $vec(X)=?$ Many thanks!

Comment: Can you give the dimensions of the other matrices ? & explain what you mean by vectorised (if needs be)

Comment: Hi, Donald, I edit the question following your suggestions. I am looking for $vec(x)$ or a solution of $X$ from the above vectorized equation. Thanks

Comment: These were the dimensions that I had figured. So we are given $A$,$B$ & $C$ and you want $X$ right ? & it is just normal regular matrix multiplication ? ... should be doable , it is $n*m$ linear equations is as many unknowns.

Comment: Do mind to give me some reference on how to get $X$ or $vec(X)$? Thanks